# Issue with bootstrap and iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, modal-dialog

Sorry in advance for my english, i'm French.

I am working on a module that is made with bootstrap .

This module is called in iframe .

This module use modal windows with bootstrap.

Is it possible to bring up these modals windows over the parent page? because I am limited in width and opacity layer is limited to width of the iframe instead of across the page ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. In your `iframe` you use an object in the parent window, like this:

```
window.parent.myMember
```

You can use functions, like this:

```
window.parent.myFunction(myParam)
```

So, if you want a modal window to be triggered from the `iframe`, but to affect the parent, then use the `window.parent` idea.